# Storing an iOS app's data remotely

Tags: ios, database

I want my app to store the user's data remotely when they sign up (possibly in a MySQL database). I have seen tutorials about retrieving data through MySQL and JSON, but I cannot seem to find anything about storing data into the MySQL database. Maybe this isn't the best way to do it?

Comment: How about using Parse.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit too vague to be able to answer implementation details, so I give an outline how I would go about the problem:

1. Determine if you want to create the service yourself or use a cloud data storage provider (some are free and provide iOS libraries. One simple example is Apple's own iCloud).
2. If you create your own service, use your favorite Web technology. Have a look at [Tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for example.
3. Use a RESTful iOS client library such as [RESTkit](http://restkit.org) to connect to your service.

If you don't have any specific requirements, I would start by investigating if Core Data + iCloud fits the requirements. That should get you up and running in the shortest time.

Comment: what about if I used parse to store my data and retrieve it. Then I would be able to avoid a complicated process. I tried parse out and I do like it. I'm just asking you in case there are any downsides with it

Comment: I have not tried parse myself, but it was the kind of service I was referring to in my #1 bullet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call a .php page from your app like below:

```
NSString *urlWithGetVars=@"http://www.somedomain.com/somepage.php?var1=avar&var2=anothervar";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlWithGetVars];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                 returningResponse:&response 
                                                             error:&error];

    //turn response data to string
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] 
                                initWithData:responseData 
                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    //check if there is any error
    if(!error)
    {
        //log the response
        NSLog(@"Response from server = %@", responseString);


    }    
    else
    {
       //log error
        NSLog(@"Error = %@",error.description);

    }
```

And in your somepage.php do the data writing process to the MySql database like below:

```
<?php
$var1=$_GET["var1"];
$var2=$_GET["var2"];

// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("yoursitehost", "usr", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("yourdb") or die(mysql_error());

// Write var1 and var2 to your mysql table
mysql_query("INSERT INTO your_table (var1,var2) VALUES ('".$var1."','".$var2."')");
or die(mysql_error());  
?>
```

There might be some coding errors if you notice anything wrong let me know...

PS: NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest is going to block the user interface so you probably don't want to use it

Comment: -1: `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:]` will block the UI if called on the main thread! To get around this, you must call it on a background thread (such as by wrapping the call within `dispatch_async()` block). Alternatively, you can use a helper library such as `AFNetworking` to make it easier to work with networking calls.

Comment: thats right it will block UI.